# Marketing Cloud Query Activity is not pulling in data for newly added fields to target Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a query running as an update to capture the data from source data extension and put it on target Data extension as update the matching records and insert new if not matching.

Yesterday we have added a new field in the target data extension to get the data from the source data extension. This field was already present in the source Data extension.

Issue is my query ran and the newly added field is coming as a blank but the value is present in the source data extension field.

Records are coming from source data extension to target but all records are having the newly created field as a blank.

Why do I observe this behavior? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to re-save your query.  The query itself is saved and hard-coded on the Marketing Cloud's side and any type of updates like this will not automatically carry over.  This is why it is best practice to specify each column name in your query so you avoid this and are forced to update the query anytime you update fields in your data extensions.

This is mentioned in our docs here:  [Optimize the Query Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_optimize_the_query_activity.htm&type=5)

Comment: My eyes have been opened. I only wish I'd read this 5 hours ago. The link you provided is also useful, but after reading it top to bottom, I didn't see this fact mentioned anywhere.